# Sum to Zero Constraint GAM Factor Interaction

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I was under the impression that the smooths fit with `mgcv` were made identifiable through a sum to zero constraint - i.e. if one was to sum the smooth over the values of its covariates, it would equal zero. This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33785/centering-constraints-for-regression-specifically-gam?lq=1) gives some background, with an excellent answer from @Gavin Simpson.

With single smooths, this seems to be the case:

```
set.seed(1234); 
dat <- gamSim(4); 

mod1<-gam(y ~ s(x1)+s(x2), data=dat) 
p<-predict(mod1,dat,type="terms")
sum(p[,1]) #[1] -8.729996e-16
sum(p[,2]) #[1] -4.956868e-12
```

But when a smooth is interacted with a factor, this is no longer the case. Is this an error in my understanding, or is something else going on?

```
mod2<-gam(y ~ s(x2, by=fac), data=dat) 
p<-predict(mod2,dat,type="terms")
head(p)
sum(p[,1]) #[1] 1.923649
sum(p[,2]) #[1] 6.496321
sum(p[,3]) #[1] 45.36179
```

Comment: Will add a fuller answer tomorrow when i recall the details, but the missing info in your by smoother is that you need to add `fac` as a fixed effects term to the model as well as the by variable. I will guess that adding that will improve things.

Comment: But wasn't the reason for adding the fac fixed effect because the smoothers without it (or with it for that matter) summed to zero?

Comment: Read section 4.3 in Simon's book (p169-170). It discusses the sum-to-zero constraint and explicitly references the model matrix, not the `"terms"` component. The constraint is $\mathbf{1^{T}\tilde{X}_j\tilde{\beta}_j} = 0$ and some re-parameterisation is done to absorb this constraint into the model matrix. So when looking at this you need to include the model matrix *and* the coefficient vector. But I am struggling to get the correct bits out of `mod2` to illustrate this. You may want to email Simon again *and* post an Answer here if he replies (or ask him if he wants to do it himself?).